Einstein structure and the quotient (group)$\frac{\operatorname{Ricc}_g}{\operatorname{Iso}_g}$
$\newcommand{\Ric}{\operatorname{Ric}}\newcommand{\Iso}{\operatorname{Iso}}$Let  $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with corresponding LC connection and Ricci tensor.
Is there an obvious  description of the  group $\Ric_g$ of  all diffeomorphisms preserving the  Ricci tensor and comparison to the isometry  group $\Iso_g$.  Is  $\Iso_g$ a  normal  subgroup of  $\Ric_g$? If it is the case  what geometric information does the  quotion group$\frac{\Ric_g}{\Iso_g}$ have?
In the particular case $\Iso(g)=\Ric_g$ can one say that the  manifold admit at least one Einstein structure?

If the Ricci tensor vanishes, for example on a CY, then the group $Ric_g$ is the diffeomorphism group, and $Iso_g$ can't be normal in it, since its conjugates are isometry groups of diffeomorphic metrics.

@BenMcKay what about finit index case:under what condition the isometry groyp is a finit3 index subgroup?

@BenMcKay  I  wonder under what conditions the group $Ric_g$ is a finite dimensional Lie group? and  what is a  sharp upper  bound for  its dimension(Inspired by similar  result on isometric group). Any way thank youn  very much for your  attention to the question

Certainly the group $\operatorname{Ric}_g$ is a finite dimensional Lie group acting smoothly whenever the Ricci tensor is definite, i.e. is a pseudo-Riemannian metric. (I don't know of a proof other than in my notes on Cartan geometries.)

@BenMcKay I would appreciate if you provid the link of your  note on Cartan Geometries.

My notes on Cartan geometries are here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.14457

@BenMcKay Thank you Ben for sharing your excelent lecture: I was revewing its furst parts, Cartan form $\omega$ as a lie algebra valued form. Is it an obvious question to ask about the integral $\int_G \omega^n$ as an element of the Lie algebra?What is this integral?

I don't know, sorry. The story of such integrals is a part of Lie algebra cohomology.

@BenMcKay  I wonder  if  the  nth power is  always  non zero?  Some  intuitions: Let's  pose  the  question of  integrability of Cartan form in the  following  sense: Choose a  functional $\phi$on the  tangent  space(the Lie  algebra) then $\phi \circ \omega$ is  a  1 form in the usual  sense hence integrability of  $\phi\circ \omega$ is in the  hand of  Frobenius   condition $\alpha \wedge d\alpha=0$ Now  with some  abuse of  notation and  abuse of  terminologies one arrive  at $\wmega \wedge \omega \wedge \omega=-\omega \wedge d\omega= 0???)

$(???)=0$ in case of integrability.  By the  way  did  you discuss this  kind of integrability in your  lecture?(The  integrability after composition with one(hence  all)  functionals  defined on $T_e G$?

@BenMcKay  Sorry  I revise  the  latex of  my previous  2  comment:  Now  with some  abuse of  notation and  abuse of terminologies one  arrive at $\omega \wedge \omega \wedge \omega=-\omega \wedge d\omega =0???$
